# Not able to write spark dataframe. Error Found nested NullType in column 'colname' which is of ArrayType

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Hi I have a pandas dataframe named df , where few of the columns contain list of strings.

```
id    colname    colname1
a1    []         []
a2    []         []
a3    []         ['anc','asf']
```

I want to write it into delta table. As per the schema of the table, the datatype of colname and colname1 are array.

But as you can see colname doesn't contain any data, so when I'm trying to write it into the table. it is giving me this error:

```
AnalysisException: Found nested NullType in column 'colname' which is of ArrayType. Delta doesn't support writing NullType in complex types.
```

This is the code for writing it to table.

```
spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(df)
spark_df.write.mode("append").option("overwriteSchema", "true").saveAsTable("dbname.tbl_name")
```

I tried to search everywhere but didn't find the solution.

What can I do so that even if the colname column is entirely empty(as in this case) the data should be successfully inserted in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your column contains only empty arrays, Spark cannot tell whether it would be array of ints or strings or whatever - finally it considers array of nulls.

Provide schema explicitly when creating DataFrame:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
schema = StructType([
           StructField("id", StringType(), True),
           StructField("colname", ArrayType(StringType()), True),
           StructField("colname1", ArrayType(StringType()), True)
         ])
spark.createDataFrame(df, schema)
```

Comment: Do I have to include all the columns in the StructType or we can only include the columns which we want, like for eg "id" column is a string type and it will never be null.

Comment: You need to include full schema, all columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just cast your array prior to writing it to delta. With this solution you don't have to define everything up front.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as sf
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, ArrayType
df = df.withColumn("colname", sf.col("colname").cast(ArrayType(StringType())))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can identify NullType columns dynamically. Here is an example how to replace them with StringType.

```py
import json

def explicit_column_type_for_null_types(df):
  json_schema_str = json.dumps(df.schema.jsonValue()).replace('"type": "void"','"type": "string"')
  new_schema = StructType.fromJson(json.loads(json_schema_str))
  return spark.createDataFrame(df.rdd, new_schema)

df_new_schema = explicit_column_type_for_null_types(spark_df)
```

Use `spark_df.printSchema()` and `df_new_schema.printSchema()` to verify that columns with only null values are now typed as `string` instead of `void`